# Styling Relative Position in respect to sibling element

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I am putting this pagination code beside table component but it is showing at extreme right position to table.
[image]

The CSS Code I applied to it is

```
.pagination{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

because of which it is floating at right and it is sibling of table. The structure is

```
<div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table-hover">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
    </div>
<div>
```

How to let the pagination be in extreme right in relative to table??

Comment: The <div> element is a block-level element. So you should set width to make them stand next to each other.

Comment: So you expect the pagination to show right after the table to the bottom-left position?

Comment: Yes and remain in extreme right of table as table expands or shortens

Comment: @AhmadRahmani , cant set the width as its responsive as I can add/delete columns in table , so its width increases/decreases.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, would you please explain more or send a pic that you want to be look like that?

Comment: the table is responsive , the table's width increases or decreases accordingly, and hence i want the pagination to be at table bottom right end as it increases/decreases.

Comment: Where should I send you the screenshot?